# PHP: Convert array argument as an individual argument for another function

Tags: php, arrays, arguments

I want to use array as an argument in my function and then convert/extract that array and apply each element into another function's argument after the first argument.

```
$args = [ $arg1, $arg2, ...];

function foo($one = 'string', $two='string', array $args = [])
{

    // my stuffs

    //here calling another function where need to pass arguments
    // the first argument is required
    // from second argument I want to apply array item individually.
    // So this function has func_get_args()
    call_another_function($one, $arg1, $arg2, ...);

}
```

So how I can convert my function array items and apply each item to `call_another_function` from second parameters to infinity based on array items

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @JohnConde how I can convert my function array items and apply each item to `call_another_function` from second parameters to infinity based on array items

Comment: Whats about the php build in function `call_user_func_array`? http://php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: call_another_funciton` is already using that to get all function arguments. Here first parameter has been sliced in that funciton using `array_slice`

Comment: @CodeLover `call_user_func_array` calls a function with the arguments as array. I will give you an example based on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can use `call_user_func_array` to call the `call_another_function` function:

```
<?php
$args = [ $arg1, $arg2, ...];

function foo($one = 'string', $two='string', array $args = [])
{

    // your stuffs

    // Put the first argument to the beginning of $args
    array_unshift($args, $one);
    // Call another function with the new arguments
    call_user_func_array('call_another_function', $args);

}

function call_another_function(){
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}

foo('one', 'two', $args);
```

this will output something like that:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(3) "one"
  [1] =>
  string(4) "arg1"
  [2] =>
  string(4) "arg2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `call_another_function` should have this signiture:

```
function call_another_function($one, $argumentsArray)
```

The second parameters is an array and you can add any number of argument to it.

```
$argumentArray = array();
array_push($argumentArray, "value1");
array_push($argumentArray, "value2");
array_push($argumentArray, "value3");
...
call_another_function($one, $argumentArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I am failed to understand it. The `call_another_function() has `$funcargs=func_get_args();` in it.